# Are there region specific hardware differences to GT-N8000?

Tags: hardware, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, localization

Are there region specific hardware differences to the GT-N8000, or is a GT-N8000 the same device no matter where you live?

I thought Samsung's model names (GT-I9300, SM-G900F, GT-N8000) were a safe way to identify the hardware inside. Are devices with the same model name, the same in all aspects except the region-specific/cell-provider-specific firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are differences. 
In India it has only A-gps

Comment: Could you add a reference to back this backup this answer?

Comment: Could you add more info to what this A-gps is (from the perspective of an unbeknown user) ? Not to mention what *Andrew* asked.

Comment: A-GPS is "Assisted-GPS", It uses cell tower locations to assist in getting a GPS position. This makes it alot faster to get a lock.